# Angularjs remove element within the link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay this is a very unique set of circumstances, but I'm trying to make my application future proof. I'm using the foundation for apps framework that provides a modal feature, but I would rather use the standard html5 `<dialog>` element where it's available. To facilitate this I've created a two directives that will only be implemented if `dialog` is not supported.

```js
(function (app, ng) {
    //Don't load if Dialog is supported
    if (document.createElement('dialog').showModal) {
        return
    }

    function dialog(ModalFactory) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                if (!scope.modals) {
                    scope.modals = {};
                }
                var config = {
                    id: attr.id,
                    contentScope: scope,
                    template: elem.html()
                };
                elem.remove(); //This Breaks Everything
                scope.modals[config.id] = new ModalFactory(config);

            }
        }
    }

    dialog.$inject = ['ModalFactory'];

    app.directive('dialog', dialog);
})(app, angular);

(function (app, ng) {
    var dialogSupport = (document.createElement('dialog').showModal);

    var modal = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem[0].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = attr.activate;
                scope.modals[id].activate();
            })
        }
    };

    var dialog = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
            elem[0].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var id = attr.activate;
                document.getElementById(id).showModal();
            })
        }
    };

    function activate() {
        return (dialogSupport) ? dialog : modal
    }

    app.directive('activate', activate);
})(app, angular);
```

```html
<dialog id="someDialog">Testing</dialog>
```

The problem is in the dialog function, when I delete the element, I get an error and the browser crashes because angular is in the middle of a `$digest` cycle. I need to remove the element though because the `ModalFactory` will create its own with the same id and I'll get another error. Plus I don't want to pollute my DOM with unnecessary items.

I've also considered changing the tag in the dialog directive to something besides ID, but then it won't work using the out of the box dialog. So what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: The question lacks the necessary details. What error exactly, did it clearly say that it is because of $digest? It is ok to remove element within link. But the design is highly questionable, it may potentially lead to memory leaks. Conditional directive definition is bad idea, there would be zero overhead for scopeless directive that executes code conditionally in link.

Comment: A memory link is probably what's happening. The browser just crashes, and the last error I get in the log is `$digest already in progress`

Comment: I see nothing really criminal in the implementation, but ModalFactory is a black box. Reproducible plunker or so would be great.